# Change Image in Update With NFC (Clear Android Intent Issue)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have the next code:

```
void Update ()
{
    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
    {
                if(!already_switched){
                try
                {
                    // Create new NFC Android object
                    AndroidJavaObject mActivity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer").GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"); // Activities open apps
                    mIntent = mActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getIntent");
                    string sAction = mIntent.Call<String>("getAction"); // resulte are returned in the Intent object
                    if (sAction == "android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED")
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Tag of type NDEF");
                    }
                    else if (sAction == "android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED")
                    {
                                            GetComponent<ButtonScrollingUp>().actual_pos = GetComponent<ButtonScrollingUp>().actual_pos + 1;
                                            if (GetComponent<ButtonScrollingUp>().actual_pos > GetComponent<ButtonScrollingUp>().images.Count) GetComponent<ButtonScrollingUp>().actual_pos = 0;
                                            image.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = GetComponent<ButtonScrollingUp>().images[GetComponent<ButtonScrollingUp>().actual_pos];
                                            text_.GetComponent<Text>().text = GetComponent<ButtonScrollingUp>().texts[GetComponent<ButtonScrollingUp>().actual_pos];

                        return;
                    }
                    else if (sAction == "android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED")
                    {
                                        tag_output_text.text += "Not supported";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tag_output_text.text = "Scan a NFC tag to make the cube disappear...";
                        return;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string text = ex.Message;
                    tag_output_text.text = text;
                }
                    }
    }

}
```

The code change an image when a NFC get close to the phone, the problem is that it changes the image one time per frame. I could do it just to change one time, but I don't want that, I want that each time that someone get close the NFC it changes. I think that I could solve that if I clear the intent stack, and I can do it with this:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

But I don't know how to do that in c# and unity.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Did you try what's in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

> I think that I could solve that if I clear the intent stack, and I can
>   do it with this:
>
> ```
> intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
> ```
>
> But I don't know how to do that in c# and unity.

You already have the intent stored in the `mIntent` variable:

```
AndroidJavaObject mActivity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer").GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"); // Activities open apps
AndroidJavaObject mIntent = mActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getIntent");
```

To get the equivalent of the **Java** code below:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

First, get the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` int values in C# from the Intent:

```
int FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK = mIntent.GetStatic<int>("FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK"); 
int FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK = mIntent.GetStatic<int>("FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK");
```

Now, you can do the bitwise operation and pass them to the `setFlags` function:

```
int orOP = FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK;
mIntent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setFlags", orOP);
```

Maybe something like this:

Comment: Yeah I try it, but it didn't work, so I tryed another thing and work using some of your code, so thank you so much, you help me a lot. I solve it marking the intents that I already read, and I ignore the marked intents.